# Set is open iff complement is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: general-topology

Is my proof of the following correct?

1. A set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is open iff $\mathbb{R^n}-A$ is closed.
2. A set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is closed iff $\mathbb{R^n}-A$ is open.

Proof. Suppose that $A$ is open. We must show that for every $x\notin \mathbb{R^n}-A$ there is a nbhd $N$ with $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-A)=\varnothing$. Let $x\notin \mathbb{R^n}-A\implies x\in A$. As $A$ is open, there is an open nbhd $N$ of $x$ such that $x\in N \subseteq A$. This implies that $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-A)=\varnothing$.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathbb{R^n}-A$ is closed. Every point $x\notin \mathbb{R^n}-A$ has a nbhd $N$ with $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-A)=\varnothing$, thus $N$ lies entirely inside $A$ (i.e., $x\in N \subseteq A$). So $A$ is open.

The second statement follows from the first by substituting $\mathbb{R^n}-A$ for $A$

Comment: Your reasoning seems solid. Note, however, that in many approaches closed sets are defined as somplementary to open sets, hence your proposition is just a definition.

Comment: What's the defintion of closed subset you use?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane $A$ is closed if every point $x\notin A$ is exterior. A point is an exterior point of $A$ if there is a nbhd $N$ of $x$ such that $N\cap A=\varnothing$

Comment: But do you not see that $x\not \in A\iff x\in A^c$ and $N\cap A=\emptyset\iff N\subset A^c$ so your defintion of $A$ is closed is  equivalent to $A^c$ is open ?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Well, *all* valid definitionms of closed are equivalent to complement of open at the end of the day ...

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane That's my proof, what do you mean 'do you not see that'?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But I mean that  this defintion of closed subset given by the OP is almost saying it's a complement of an open subset.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane It's an exercise in a book. Is my proof correct?

Comment: @saadtaame Yes, it's fine. Though your second part should should formally start with $x\in A$ and not iwth the (equivalent of course) $x\notin \mathbb R^n-A$.

Comment: Yes it's correct. Good job.

Comment: I fail altogether to understand the downvote: the OP has clearly invested effort in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first paragraph in your proof is absolutely right. The Second claim is most easily done by using the first one and the fact
$$\Bbb R^n - \left(\Bbb R^n - A\right)=A.$$

Answer (score 0):

1) $(\implies)$ You are almost there, assume $A$ is an open set. Let $x\in A$, then we can find an open set $O$ such that $x\in O \subset A $ which implies $O \cap A^c = \phi$ since $A \cap A^c = \phi.$

**Note:** $A^c=R^n\setminus A$ is the complement.

Comment: It seems to me that you’re just restating the OP’s argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Not exactly. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I see no significant difference, and no basis for the assertion that the OP is only *almost* there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Note that, the OP is saying $N \subseteq A$ and it should be $\subset$.

Comment: Eh? There’s certainly nothing wrong with $N\subseteq A$. Indeed, by any possible definition of *neighborhood* it is certainly possible that $A$ **is** a nbhd of $x$.